# VBA to GetElementByID on a Web form

Tags: vba

I'm having a bit of trouble with my VBA code filling in a form on an intranet page. It generally works okay but every so often, the ID's of the fields on this form change and I have to update my code but not until I've had lots of errors reported. Is there anyway I can use a wildcard, or loop through the possibilities before it tries to fill out the form? The bit of code I'm using is

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Template_ctl24_ctl00_Shelfmark" & x & "_TextField").value = Range("Q" & x + 11).value
```

But the ID can change to Template_ctl22_ctl00.... or Template_ctl25_ctl00.... for a reason unknown to me. I don't have control over that area - i'm really only front end. 
So is there some variation on using a * wildcard? 
Or looping through whether the ID is a 22, 24, 25 or whatever before it proceeds? 
What can and can't you do with this sort of line of VBA code?

Thanks in advance

Paul

Comment: Are you shure you want to do some kind of guessing about the IDs of the fields? Sounds quite flaky. How can you be sure that you got hold of the right one?

Comment: Well all the ID's on that page start off with that same bit of text. They're always either 22,24 or 25. It's the x variable that changes within a loop I've got so it gets the correct one. Just that initial part that's causing the problem.

Comment: @actionjack You may refer my answer as an example which does the putting and pulling the data from webpage. If you found the answer helpful then please vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know where the element is positioned on the page it would be much better to locate it using something like `getElementsByTagName`.

However, you could use a simple loop. In the following I've assumed the attempt to reference a non-existing element results in `Nothing`, but perhaps it generates an error - I haven't tested. If so, you'll need to use error-handling code instead.

```
Dim elem As Variant

For x = 22 To 25
    Set elem = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Template_ctl24_ctl00_Shelfmark" _
        & x & "_TextField")
    If Not elem Is Nothing Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next x
If elem Is Nothing Then
    'Doh! not found
Else
    'obtain elem.value
End If
```